# Failing to install TensorFlow from a MinGW shell

Tags: python, tensorflow, mingw, mingw-w64

Trying to install TensorFlow from binary (Python works correctly), from the MinGW64 shell, I get a sequence of the following error message.

I am using the MinGW64 shell since these machines Windows' command prompt has been disabled.

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

> Collecting tensorflow   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
>   read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/

The internet connection of this machine is fine. Could it be that it is not seen by MinGW64?

Second attempt: download TensorFlow manually (i.e. from the browser, as a `whl` file), and:

```
$ pip3 install -e ./tensorflow-1.5.0rc0/
```

> Directory './tensorflow-1.5.0rc0/' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.

```
$ pip3 install -e ./tensorflow-1.5.0rc0/tensorflow-1.5.0rc0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

> ./tensorflow-1.5.0rc0/tensorflow-1.5.0rc0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+

```
$ pip3 install ./tensorflow-1.5.0rc0/tensorflow-1.5.0rc0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

> Processing
>   tensorflow-1.5.0rc0\tensorflow-1.5.0rc0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
>   Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow==1.5.0rc0)   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after
>   connection broken by
>
> 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/wheel/
>   ...
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel>=0.26 (from
>   tensorflow==1.5.0rc0) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found
>   for wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow==1.5.0rc0)

---

Platform details:

`- Windows 7
- Python 3.6.4
- TensorFlow 1.4
- Shell: MinGW64`

Comment: check your firewall settings and ensure that MinGW-w64 is allowed access to the internet

Comment: `$ ping -n 5 www.example.com`   -->   "Ping request could not find host www.example.com. Please check the name and try again."  @Usernamenotfound: you must be right.

Comment: worst case, download from pypi.org and install using path on pip

Comment: Switched to another network. Ping is now OK. From `pip3` I get the same errors as before.

Comment: Just download the tar file from pypi.python.org and install using pip?

Comment: Question updated. Thank you.

Comment: just try `pip install [filename]` without the -e?

Comment: I updated my question with the output without the -e option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install wheel: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel